# Buttons not enabling/disabling

Tags: c#, events, button, visible

My program runs a test over a serial connection.  After I click the RUN TEST button everything works great. The RUN TEST button disappears and the STOP button pops up.  Data collection runs as expected.  My problem is that the STOP button doesn't respond.  All of my testing code is run under the RUN TEST button click event. Is this uninterruptible by my second button?

Note: I use the whateverButton.enable and whateverButton.visible properties.  Is there another one I need to set to get this to work?

```
runButton.Enabled = false;
runButton.Visible = false;
STOPbutton.Enabled = true;
STOPbutton.Visible = true;
```

The rest of the program is to big to fully include.

Any help with this would greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you handling the Stop action in your running thread?  Are you checking for stop?

Comment: Are you trying to make the `STOPbutton` visible in the middle of this long running process?

Comment: You need to run your code on a new thread. Running from the click handler blocks the rest of the UI

Comment: Do all of your other controls on the form become unresponsive as well?  You could be running into a threading issue where your code is locking up the UI thread, in which case the STOP button will not be clickable.

Comment: ... and if a button is not visible how does it matter it's disabled as well?

Comment: If you are handling everything in the same handler, it is smarter to just update the `Text` in the button. (After you have fixed any threading issues, obviously)

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess - you disable the "Run", enable the "Stop", perform your task, reverse the enable/disable on "Run" and "Stop"?

Your issue is that the UI is not updated because the UI thread is busy running your task.

Use `BackgroundWorker` or `Task.Run` to spawn a new thread for the task, some significant refactoring may need to happen to take UI interaction out of the background thread and to support cancelling.